# Model.reopen() causes store to return ProxyObject on first page load

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to override `Model.save()` globally for all models. So I created initializer...

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export function initialize(appInstance) {
  DS.Model.reopen({
    save() {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  });
}

export default {
  after: ['ember-data'],
  name: 'model-save',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Looks good but works only page reload, otherwise the `save()` is undefined and model is ProxyObject with desired model inside.

```
// route
model() {
  return this.get('store').findRecord('product', 1); 
}

// controller
const model = this.get('model');
console.log(model);
console.log(model.save);
console.log(model.content.save); // contains working save function
```

Console output on first boot-up:

[image: stack]

Console output after F5:

[image: stack]

This is enough to break it.

```
// app/app.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';
import DS from 'ember-data';
DS.Model.reopen();
```

I tried to replicate this bug on clean project but without success. This is only place with `reopen()`. It behaves same in chrome and firefox.

**Edit:**

I heavily edited question because old version was focusing on wrong cause of the bug.

Comment: You should probably specify that it should run after the `ember-data` initializer.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help. I updated question with screenshot when console is opened during boot-up. Maybe that will provide some clue.

Comment: Strange. The first screenshot (closed console) makes it look like `this.get('model');` is returning an instance of `Ember.ObjectProxy` instead of `DS.Model` which explains why it doesn't have the `save` method. I'm not sure why the value of `this.get('model')` changes based on of the console is opened or closed.

Comment: You are right, and content of the proxy object is indeed desired model. I also tested this in firefox and it is same there.

Comment: How did you see the console output if it was closed?

Comment: This may fall into the category of "keep doing different things until something works". One "different thing" you could try is putting the `DS.Model.reopen` right at the top level of `app.js`.

Comment: I can open console once the error occurs the log is there but the behavior is based on state of console during ember boot.

Comment: I doubt if this is related, but one thing we know is that caching is turned off (if you so choose) while the console is open.

Comment: Thanks for help. Just tried ```reopen()``` on top level of ```app/app.js``` and it is the same. If you mean cache checkbox in network tab in chrome then I already tried that too and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If you haven't already, might want to post this to the Ember list where people who know would be more likely to see it. By the way, one workaround might be to do `myModel = DS.Model.extend({save})` and then derive your individual models from that.

Comment: What is ember lists url? Workaround with extend or mixin should work but it is large project with 40 models so I am not really happy with redefining all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours later I discovered that this bug occurs based on landing page and is not related to browser in any way and later core cause. I have to admit, I found code that creates proxy and passes it through link-to helper. Thanks everyone for help.